# Cygwin commands are not running under Emacs

Tags: microsoft-windows, cygwin, mobaxterm

I installed  emacs packages from MobaXterm.
When I'm in MobaXterm terminal I could run any Cygwin commands e.g. 'ls' or 'which' but when I start Emacs and call the shell it does not recognize any of unix command.

```
sh-4.1$ ls
sh: ls: command not found
sh-4.1$ pwd
/drives/c/Software/MobaXterm_Portable_v22.0
sh-4.1$ ls
sh: ls: command not found
sh-4.1$ which pwd
sh: which: command not found
sh-4.1$
```

Obviously I messed with settings but could someone help to resolve it?

Comment: Are you actually running a Cygwin build of Emacs?

Comment: If "MobaXterm" is *not* something inherently to do with Cygwin, are you starting Emacs from that terminal/shell?

Comment: sorry, my fault .. it's not emacsclient. I did not install Cygwin because I think that MobaXterm is using Cygwin itself. Note: in MobaXterm terminal it uses all Cygwin utilities and commands. My issue is that when I start Emacs ( I installed it as a package from MobaXterm) and open Emacs shell and want to run any unix-like command e.g. 'ls' it doesn't work. Hence my issue is only with Emacs and only related to unix-like commands from the shell

Comment: I've edited tags for you to remove `emacsclient` -- but that's something you could have done yourself.  If you know you can improve the question, go ahead and edit it.

Comment: I still can't tell whether you're running `emacs` from inside the mobaxterm terminal/shell session, either.  You didn't really answer that question.  If not, does doing that make a difference?

Answer (score -1):

Folks
Sorry not being clear how I started EMacs. I started it from inside of MobaXterm.
I figured out that I installed different versions of Emacs packages into MobaXterm.
A few of it has the issues with prompt while others don’t have it
Hence I was able to create a shortcut to “good” one and I  am all set now
Thanks for trying to help